# formatting large text files in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, text-files

I have been stuck with this piece of code for while trying to determine if I should use parallel programming.

The code takes a text file with two columns: the first column contains a word and the second an URL.

In the String_stripper_function() each row of the text file is formatted in a specific way (hence all the call to the replace() function.).

Then we make a comparison between the first column and the second column if the word in the first column is contained in the url in the second column then the row is written to a new file (call it `Result.txt`).

Moreover, if the word in the first column contains 4 capital letters and the URL in the second column has a number then add the row to the same new file (`Result.txt`).

Now this works and I have checked multiple times, but it takes and exceedingly long time, a **few hours for 1000000 rows** on an **i7** machine with 16GB of RAM.

The file contains 1923014 lines (or rows if you will); it is 97.9 MB.

So my question is: performance-wise **is there something wrong with my code**?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Apr 12 16:44:35 2015

@author: Steve
"""
import re
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
    #This code strips the urls into their main domain
def url_stripper(url):
    url=url.replace('http://','')
    url=url.replace('https://','')
    url=url.replace('http','')
    url=url.replace('/',' ')
    url=url.split()
    return url


def String_stripper_function():
   with open("homepages.txt") as infile:
    i=0
    l1=np.array([])
    l2=np.array([])
    l3=np.array([])
    l4=np.array([])
    for line in infile:        
        word_original=line.split()[0]
        url_original=line.split()[1]
        url=url_stripper(url_original)
        if len(url)==0:
            print 'lol no url fam'
        else:
            url=url[0]
        word=word_original.replace('_',' ')
        word=word.replace('-',' ')
        word=word.replace('(','')
        word=word.replace(')','')
        regex = re.compile(".*?\((.*?)\)")
        word_in_parenthesis = re.findall(regex, word)
        for i in xrange(len(word_in_parenthesis)):
            word=word.replace(word_in_parenthesis[i],'')
        word=word.replace('The ','')
        word=word.replace(' The ','')
        word=word.replace(', The ','')
        word=word.replace(' ,The ','')
        word=word.replace(',The ','')
        word=word.replace('...','')
        word=word.replace('A ','')
        word=word.replace(' A ','')
        word=word.replace(', A ','')
        word=word.replace(' ,A ','')
        word=word.replace(',A ','')
        word=word.replace('An ','')
        word=word.replace(' An ','')
        word=word.replace(', An ','')
        word=word.replace(' ,An ','')
        word=word.replace(',An ','')
        word=word.replace(',','')
        #condition 2&3
        words=word.split()
#        print word.lower().split()
#        print url_original.lower()
        Capital_Letters=sum(1 for c in word if c.isupper())
        decision=hasNumbers(url)
        for w in words:
            #comment the following for 
            if w.lower() in url_original.lower():
                if word_original not in l1:
                    l1=np.append(l1,word_original)
                    l2=np.append(l2,url_original)
                else:
                    print ""
                #Uncomment the following for Domain only
#            if w.lower() in url.lower():
#                    l1=np.append(l1,word_original)
#                    l2=np.append(l2,url_original)
            elif Capital_Letters==4 and decision==True:
                if word_original not in l1:
                    l1=np.append(l1,word_original)
                    l2=np.append(l2,url_original) 
                else:
                    print ""
#        if word_original not in l1:
#            if word_original not in l3:
#                    l3=np.append(l3,word_original)
#                    l4=np.append(l4,url_original)
            else:
                print ""


    file = open("results.txt", "w")
    for index in xrange(len(l1)):
        file.write( '%s \t %s\n' % (str(l1[index]),str(l2[index])))
    file.close()
#    file1 = open("results_failedConditions.txt", "w")
#    for index in xrange(len(l3)):
#        file1.write( '%s \t %s\n' % (str(l3[index]),str(l4[index])))
#    file1.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
         String_stripper_function()
```

Comment: Seems like there is an excessive amount of .replace() functions going on. You can probably replace each group of .replace() with one regular expression.

Comment: Have you profiled this code? Do you have an approximate idea of the time complexity of it? As @Malonge says, the various `replace` calls are probably not helping.

Comment: @TobiaTesan No I haven't profiled the code. But thanks will do asap.
I have also changed the excessive replace to a forloop but obviously this does not solve the entire problem.

Comment: regexp compilation on every cycle loop, processing line by line without paralleling the work or working on a bulk of data, usage of numpy on a level of base python array(framework overhead), process every word in a cycle...what you expect? :)

Comment: Speaking of which, I'm not sure there is a reason for using `numpy` here. We work almost exclusively on characters.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this question should probably be asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

I have made a few changes to your code to take into account a few assumptions.

1. `str.replace()` runs faster by running it over a single large string than iterating line by line.
2. In `urlStripper` I just found `://` because I believe that the beginning is only time this happens.
3. Instead of using `.replace("/"," ")` and then `.split()`, it should be faster to just `.split("/")`. You can split with your own delimiter. See [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) in the docs.

I made a few other small changes. On my testing, my version of running a test of 500 pages 1000 times, this version took 0.054 secs, while your version took 0.133 secs. 
Here is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Apr 12 16:44:35 2015

@author: Steve
@edit: IronManMark20
"""
import timer
import re
def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
    #This code strips the urls into their main domain
def url_stripper(url):
    try:
        index=url.index("://") #only happens at beginning
    except:
        return url.split("/") #you can set the splitter
    url=url[:index]
    return url.split("/")



def String_stripper_function():
    with open("./homepages.txt") as infile:
        i=0
        l1=[]
        l2=[]
        #l3=[]
        #l4=[]
        lines_string="" #We'll use this later
        uris=[]#needed for uris
        for line in infile:
            word_original=line.split()[0]
            url_original=line.split()[1]
            url=url_stripper(url_original)
            if len(url)==0:
                print 'lol no url fam'
            else:
                url=url[0]
            lines_string+=word_original
            lines_string+="/" #add a delimiter that we don't search for later
            uris+=[url_original]
        words=Mass_List(lines_string)
        words=words[:len(words)-1]
        for w in words:
            lines=lines_string.split("/")#split for later use
            Capital_Letters=sum(1 for c in w if c.isupper())
            url_original=uris[words.index(w)] #get url for each line
            decision=hasNumbers(url_original)

            #comment the following for 
            if w.lower() in url_original.lower():
                if word_original not in l1:
                    l1+=[lines[words.index(w)]]
                    l2+=[uris[words.index(w)]]
            #   else:
            #       print ""
                #Uncomment the following for Domain only
#           if w.lower() in url.lower():
#                    l1=np.append(l1,word_original)
#                    l2=np.append(l2,url_original)
            elif Capital_Letters==4 and decision==True:
                if word_original not in l1:
                    l1+=[lines[words.index(w)]]
                    l2+=[uris[words.index(w)]]
            #   else:
            #       print ""
#           if word_original not in l1:
#               if word_original not in l3:
#                    l3=np.append(l3,word_original)
#                    l4=np.append(l4,url_original)
            #else:
            #   print ""


    file = open("results.txt", "w") 
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        file.write(l1[i]+" "+l2[i]+"\n")
    file.close()
#    file1 = open("results_failedConditions.txt", "w")
#    for index in xrange(len(l3)):
#        file1.write( '%s \t %s\n' % (str(l3[index]),str(l4[index])))
#    file1.close()
def Mass_List(lines):
        word=lines.replace('_',' ')
        word=word.replace('-',' ')
        word=word.replace('(','')
        word=word.replace(')','')
        regex = re.compile(".*?\((.*?)\)")
        word_in_parenthesis = re.findall(regex, word)
        for i in xrange(len(word_in_parenthesis)):
            word=word.replace(word_in_parenthesis[i],'')
        word=word.replace('The ','')
        word=word.replace(' The ','')
        word=word.replace(', The ','')
        word=word.replace(' ,The ','')
        word=word.replace(',The ','')
        word=word.replace('...','')
        word=word.replace('A ','')
        word=word.replace(' A ','')
        word=word.replace(', A ','')
        word=word.replace(' ,A ','')
        word=word.replace(',A ','')
        word=word.replace('An ','')
        word=word.replace(' An ','')
        word=word.replace(', An ','')
        word=word.replace(' ,An ','')
        word=word.replace(',An ','')
        word=word.replace(',','')
        words=word.split('/') #changed to split in arbitrary delimiter
        return words

if __name__=="__main__":
         String_stripper_function()
```